# Watching a file for changes in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application for Windows 7 where I would like to watch a file for changes.

The file may be changed like this:

```
std::ofstream myfile_;

void LogData( const char* data )
{
    myfile_ << data << std::endl;
    // note that the file output buffer is flushed by std::endl, but the file is not closed.
}
```

I have tried watching the file's directory using both ReadDirectoryChangesW and FindFirstChangeNotification with `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` flags. But, neither of those APIs will detect file changes until the file handle is actually closed.

Is there any way to detect a change when the file is actually written, but before the file handle is closed?

Thanks,
PaulH

---

**Update**
On @Edwin's suggestion, I'm attempting to use the Journal feature. But, I'm having a couple issues.

1. FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL returns instantly. It does not block. (though, this may be related to issue 2)
2. Regardless of where my handle points to (I have tried opening a handle to the directory "C:\Foo\Bar" and to the file "C:\Foo\Bar\MyFile.txt") I seem to get any changes made to the the C: volume. Is there a way to limit what `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL` gives me?

Error checking omitted for brevity.

```
boost::shared_ptr< void > directory( 
    ::CreateFileW( L"C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Myfile.txt", 
                   GENERIC_READ, 
                   FILE_SHARE_READ, 
                   NULL, 
                   OPEN_EXISTING, 
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                   NULL ), 
    ::CloseHandle );

USN_JOURNAL_DATA journal = { 0 };
DWORD returned = 0;
::DeviceIoControl( directory.get(), FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, NULL, 0, &journal, sizeof( journal ), &returned, NULL );

BYTE buffer[ 4096 ] = { 0 };
READ_USN_JOURNAL_DATA read = { 0, USN_REASON_DATA_EXTEND | USN_REASON_DATA_TRUNCATION, FALSE, 0, 0, journal.UsnJournalID };
::DeviceIoControl( directory.get(), FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL, &read, sizeof( read ), &buffer, sizeof( buffer ), &returned, NULL );

for( USN_RECORD* record = ( USN_RECORD* )( buffer + sizeof( USN ) );
     ( ( BYTE* )record - buffer ) < returned;
     record = ( USN_RECORD* )( ( BYTE* )record + record->RecordLength ) )
{
    ATLTRACE( L"%s\r\n", record->FileName );
}
```

Example output (none of these are in the C:\Foo\Bar directory):

```
AeXProcessList.txt`
AeXProcessList.txt`
AeXAMInventory.txt`
AeXAMInventory.txt`
AeXProcessList.txt`
AeXProcessList.txtP
access.log`
mysqlgeneral.log
E804.tmp
apache_error.log
E804.tmp
CHROME.EXE-5FE9909D.pfh
CHROME.EXE-5FE9909D.pfp
SyncData.sqlite3-journal
CHROME.EXE-5FE9909D.pfh
CHROME.EXE-5FE9909D.pfP
1211.tmp
SyncData.sqlite3-journal
AeXAMInventory.txt
```

Comment: Nice try ! But it involves a little more work! I'm searching the Net for some info for you. Be back in a few minutes!

Comment: found what I learned from : http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0999/journal/journal.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1099/journal2/journal2.aspx

Comment: I modified the example code to monitor a specific file instead of the entire volume, and it also seems to watch all system files and not just the one specified. Although, I note that it is able to detect file modification after a flush() and not just on close(). So, it definitely works better than the other methods.

Comment: I admitt ,it's not the most easy to use (understatement) ,but it does deliver the information needed. Wish it was much less complicated. And I'm no expert on this at all. You should google on it ,for better information than I can give. Hope to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> Change Journal Operations

(see MSDN docs)

That's the only 100% garanteed way to detect any change in the filesystem.
But it's pretty complicated.

Comment: As I understand it, that will tell me what changes were made, but I don't see a mechanism for being alerted when a change is made.

Comment: I'm sure of this but I seem to remember that when used correctly there is a blocking operation (through DeviceIoControl) that returns when a achange has been made in file\directory that you specify (? READ_USN_JOURNAL_DATA) in the filter ReasonMask.

Comment: Like I said it's pretty complicated. You must study the docs carefully. There are some examples on Internet ,but I cannot remember them (their on my other machine that's unaccessible now).

Comment: Besides the blocking usage I mentioned above ,you can of course also use the overlapped version of DeviceIoControl.

Comment: Okay. I'll take a second look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To read data for a specific file or directory, I believe you want to use [`FSCTL_READ_FILE_USN_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364584.aspx) instead of `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL`. I believe the latter always retrieves data for an entire volume. That does not, however, fill in the `TimeStamp`, `Reason`, or `SourceInfo` fields of the USN record you get. If you need those, I believe you can read them with `FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL`, specifying the exact USN you want to read.

Comment: Good point ,I forgot that one (or more) of those FSCTL-codes doesn't deliver the Timestamp and Reason info. It's so ... complicated !

Answer (score 0):

No, because until you close the file handle there is no guarantee a single byte ever gets written by the OS.

The exception would probably be by calling `flush` on your file handle and then call the Windows API function `FlushFileBuffers`, but unless the program writing into the file does this no bytes probably get written.

Comment: `std::endl` performs a flush. see: 27.6.2.7 If I open the file in notepad (before the handle is closed) I can see the data has been written.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a filter driver that monitors the FASTIO_WRITE and IRP_MJ_WRITE operations.  [Here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=446) is a pretty good how-to article.

Comment: A) not the only way; b) depends on the (good) behaviour of other (previous) filter drivers; C) Only Change Journals garantee 100% detection of ANY change.

Comment: I don't think other poorly behaved filter drivers is a practical concern, but I did edit my answer to remove the words "only way."  It can also be done with DeviceIoControl, but not in real time, which is what the OP seems to want.  Using DeviceIoControl will require polling, which is a really ugly solution unless it can be done very at a very leisurely pace.

Comment: There is usage of the DeviceIoControl function with properly setup data-structure that doesn't need polling and will only return when either a timeout has passed or the requested change has occured.

Comment: I appreciate the filter driver suggestion, but I think before I do that I will open and close the file on every write.